# Converting/importing Illustrator files into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, adobe-illustrator

I have hundreds of Illustrator .ai files that are picture graphs. The underlying numerical data in the graphs appears in the following format:

Illustrator
[image: Illustrator]

Is there any way to mass convert all the data "tables" from Illustrator into Excel?

Comment: You can try looking at [this](https://github.com/Silly-V/Adobe-Illustrator/blob/master/Variable%20Importer/VariableImporter.jsx) and  [this](https://sttk3.com/blog/tips/illustrator/duplicate-graph-data.html), but most people seem more interested in Importing data to Illustrator.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a real fun task. So, fortunately with some Illustrator scripting, it's possible to 'extract' this data from the documents and into a text format. Unfortunately this format is Illustrator-variable-data XML syntax type of file which may be possible to use XSLT on or using some code to parse (or edit first and then parse) the Ai-XML structure.

But before you even get there, the scripting task which would lie ahead would be to batch-process all your documents and during this process find all the graphs in a document and create a new graph-data variable for every one of them and create a new data-set. Then you'll have your script export the variables .xml files which you will later need to also work-over in some kind of way to suit your needs.

All this is assuming that you don't already have variable-data-sets in your documents in the first place, and if they do then it may take some additional work to erase the old variables and re-attach them in the fashion you prefer. Or it may be that your documents have a single data-set already in place how you need, in which case it may make it all slightly less work.

I hope this helps!